# IDW result plots at incorrect resolution

Tags: r, plot, interpolation, raster

I am not confident about the result of this Inverse Distance Weighting plot. The resolution seem incorrect.

text =
name,long,lat,waterLevel,elevation,depth
EM_01,18.553392,-34.07027,14.4,20.358,63.0
EM_27,18.574777,-34.068709,16.196,19.966,48.0

EM_29,18.613985,-34.053271,18.766,25.477,39.0

EM_20,18.654089,-34.045177,20.102,36.502,45.0

EM_23,18.643495,-34.037468,22.915,32.715,33.0

EM_13,18.637267,-34.029194,25.516,29.716,33.0
EM-14,18.625365,-34.018362,31.427,33.027,27.0
CR18_1,18.598339,-33.99808,40.1,41.0,27.0
EM_22,18.590851,-34.015547,33.85,34.85,37.0
EM_34,18.570416,-33.990289,23.586,25.286,26.0

EM_08,18.544216,-34.011639,15.641,23.641,39.0

```r
install.packages("sf")
install.packages("gstat")
install.packages("units")
install.packages("terra")

library(sf) 
library(gstat) # geostatistics
library(units) # units of measure
library(terra) 

file = 'text.txt'

#-- import
cfaq <- read.csv(file, header = 1, sep = ',', dec = '.') 

#- set as a spatial feature with xy coords an existing projection
cfaq.sf <- st_as_sf(cfaq, coords=c("long", "lat"), crs = 4326) 

#- transform to local crs
cfaq.sf <- st_transform(cfaq.sf, crs = 32734)
cfaq.sf$X <- st_coordinates(cfaq.sf)[, "X"]
cfaq.sf$Y <- st_coordinates(cfaq.sf)[, "Y"]

#-- construct empty grid
# values(grid) <- NA_real_
cfaq.bb <- st_bbox(cfaq.sf)
cfaq.bb[c("xmin","ymin")] <-   floor(cfaq.bb[c("xmin","ymin")]/1000)*1000
cfaq.bb[c("xmax","ymax")] <- ceiling(cfaq.bb[c("xmax","ymax")]/1000)*1000

#- 1km grid
grid <- st_as_stars(cfaq.bb, dx = 1000)

#-- idw
idw_results <- list()
idp_values <- c(0.5, 1, 2.5, 10)
for (idp in idp_values) {
  idw_result <- idw(log(waterLevel) ~ 1, cfaq.sf, grid, idp = idp)
  idw_results[[as.character(idp)]] <- idw_result
}

# Plot IDW results with overlay of original points
num_plots <- length(idp_values)
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))  # Arrange plots in 2 rows and 2 columns

# Create a color palette for the IDW result
color_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "green", "yellow", "red"))(50)

for (i in 1:num_plots) {
  idp <- idp_values[i]
  idw_result <- idw_results[[as.character(idp)]]
  title <- paste("IDW Interpolation (IDP =", idp, ")", sep = " ")
  
  # Plot interpolated surface
  image(idw_result, main = title, col = color_palette, #terrain.colors(50),
        xlab = "Eastings (m)", ylab = "Northings (m)",
        xlim = c(min.x, max.x), ylim = c(min.y, max.y))
  
  # Overlay original points
  points(cfaq.sf$X, cfaq.sf$Y, pch = 20, 
         bg=sp::bpy.colors(length(cfaq.sf$waterLevel))[rank(cfaq.sf$waterLevel)],
         cex=0.4*cfaq.sf$waterLevel/max(cfaq.sf$waterLevel))
         #col = "red")
  
  contour(idw_result, add = TRUE, nlevels = 10, col = "black")
}

# Reset layout to default
par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
```

[image]

The result seems incorrect. The cell size of the `IDW` raster does not change however I change the `dx` [-> here: `grid <- st_as_stars(cfaq.bb, dx = 1000)`]. What have I done wrong?